# How to organize my Buttons in Row layout and full width

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I would like to have my two divs(Up and down buttons) organized in a layout row side by side and taking the full widh of the page.
right now, they are organized like this :
[image]

My HTML is this :

```
 <div layout="row">
    <div class="btn btn-info btn-lg" width="50%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span> Up
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-info btn-lg" width="50%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> Down
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div layout="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span> Up
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> Down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek. Worked like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using boostrap you can do it in following way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-full-width">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span> Up
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-full-width">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> Down
            </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-full-width { width: 100%; }
```

Edit: added CSS class for buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot Blady214. I've added the <div class="col-xs-6"> because I need it to be the same for mobile view